# how to enable mouse to move object in play mode in unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4, game-development, unreal-blueprint

I am new to unreal engine. I am trying to make a magnet in an unreal engine. using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--xR0aQ2rB0. I am Stuck at testing I have made as he shows and then I tried to move the magnet in play mode but It is complete not showing me any mouse cursor to move the magnet I tried shift+fn+f1 but not result. I am Having Lenovo ideapad320 I5ISK laptop. In the editor, I am able to move Object.

for reference check out the video at 19:33 like he's able to move the magnet in playmode I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Please it's been days I am searching for a solution but do not find it.

Comment: Hello Nitin! Are you still having this issue? If so, can you elaborate a little more? This seems like an issue related to your Physics Handle implementation rather than the Editor itself. Are you sure you're attaching the new object to the handle? are Physics enabled? Is the object Movable?

Comment: @Fritz Thank you for your concern. I have figured out how to move the magnets in play mode. After pressing f2 I was able to move magnets.